# Is there any software for check the traffic speed of Interface?

Tags: open-source

I limited the Juniper Switch EX3300's Interface input and output traffic speed.

But I want to test wether the configuration is work.

Is there any software for check this port speed limit function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options actually, though many of them are easiest to use on UNIX-like platforms.

Possibilities include:

- [netperf](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/netperf/): One of the original network performance benchmarks, I haven't used it personally, but lots of people do use it and the results are generally considered to be very accurate.
- [iperf3](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/): Designed for testing bandwidth at layer 4, gives very easy to understand results and has good documentation.  THis is what I would personally recommend.
- [nuttcp](http://www.nuttcp.net/Welcome%20Page.html): A second derivative of one of the original TCP performance testing tools.  I've not used it much myself, but know a lot of people who have.
- [bing](http://fgouget.free.fr/bing/index-en.shtml): A rather neat tool that uses ICMP to test links with minimal overhead, which can actually test sub-sections of the full path between two systems.
- [bwping](https://bwping.sourceforge.io/): Uses ICMP just like bing, and also reports on RTT and some other info you would normally get from the regular `ping` command.
- [flowgrind](https://github.com/flowgrind/flowgrind/): Similar to iperf, but allows tracking multiple links simultaneously.
- As spartan as it may seem, combining `netcat`/`nc` and `dd` can actually give you reasonably good estimates of network performance for lower speed (1 GbE and less) links.

Comment: Iperf is what we generally use at work. Thanks for the others  (+1)